# Are these 2 pairs of the same circuits?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I started reading schematics people make. I am not used to a bunch of voltage source dot and ground symbols. In high school physics, it's always loops from which you can tell if the circuits is parallel or series.

**pair A**

[image]

**pair B**

[image]

The reasoning in both cases is that the negative end of the battery is simply the ground.

Comment: Yes, these are equivalent.

Comment: Just in case. Don't try to build them. You should never fix the potential of low impedance source. This means, the output of the amp is a supply you shouldn't ground it unless you want some burnt IC

Comment: Don't worry, there is no power to this opamp.

Comment: Ground is just a marking of a common node. It tells the reader that everything is connected together though a single common node.

Answer (score 1):

Yes both of them are equivalent one configuration simply uses the dot configuration and other uses DC Source configuration. [Check more details of both configurations here.](http://www.ielectricalengineering.com/point-sources-in-circuit-diagrams/)
[image: Amplifier point source example]

Answer (score 0):

## it depends on context

i.e. "who drew this schematic?"

In school or theoretical contexts, you are likely to use "ideal" op-amps, with the following assumptions:

- 2 power supplies (positive, negative)
- positive supply = infinity volts
- negative supply = -infinity volts
- ground = 0 volts

In pro audio, it's safer to assume

- +15V (positive supply)
- -15V (negative)
- 0V (ground)

In other contexts, the positive supply might be 5V, the negative supply might be 0V, and the ground might be anywhere in that range (inclusive!).  There might even be multiple "grounds" with different meanings (a circuit may have both "digital" and "analog" grounds).

While "ground equals 0V" is often correct, when you're dealing with real-world circuits faulty assumptions can be deadly, so check first.

### bonus anecdote

A friend of mine was working on a telescope in an extremely dry observatory in Chile, and when the motors would activate, the sensitive electronics would get damaged and logic circuits would exhibit spurious false triggers.  Because the earth itself was so dry, the "earth ground" didn't have low enough impedance to effectively isolate the different circuits.  I think their solution involved driving lots of copper rods into the dirt in many locations, and running fat copper grounding straps to the sensitive electronics.